# Can I compile Dalvik for WinCE? How?

Tags: windows-ce, dalvik

mY general question above and simple - can I compile Dalvik VM for WinCE? In particular, I want to run some android-compatible projects under WinCE 5.0. Obviously, it's sounds afraid, but interesting for me:)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it would help you. In fact, since the code is just Java, you could compile it for regular JVM and there are some for WinCE. The problem is you'd need the user interface and system libraries and porting those would be huge amount of work.

If you are writing the application, the best I can suggest is that you use some kind of portability layer. There are e.g. [J2ME polish](http://www.j2mepolish.com),  [LWUIT](https://lwuit.dev.java.net/) ([Android port](http://www.pader-sync.com/lwuit-for-blackberry-and-android.html)) and certainly more. With those you will be able to run on most mobile devices that have Java.